# Change File Encoding of Apache Tomcat on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have exhausted all my options in trying to configure my test Elastic Beanstalk Server.

I want my application to accept Chinese characters so I want to change the file.encoding to UTF8.

This is the closest I have gotten to solution but this doesn't change the current non-UTF8 encoding.

I created a .ebextensions folder with environment.config file below

```
files:
  "/tmp/update_tomcat_server_xml.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

container_commands:
  00_update_tomcat_server_xml:
    command: source /tmp/update_tomcat_server_xml.sh
```

I can see the 00_update_tomcat_server_xml in the instance logs but this doesn't change tomcats character set.

Also can I mention I am using the SpringBoot embedded Tomcat container.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass additional Tomcat specific options using the jvmoptions option setting as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-tomcat-elasticbeanstalkcontainertomcatjvmoptions).

Can you try using the following ebextension config:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
      option_name: JVM Options
      value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Let me know how it goes!